# Bootstrap inherit height from parent with the margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help with splitting the height of the parent div between the child divs with the CSS, but the 2 child divs overflow out of the parent. I need them be 50% of the parent + the margin space

Live [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1za2mdtc/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-sm-12 NoPadding"><div class="Data"></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 NoPadding"><div class="Data"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 210px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.row {
    height: inherit;
}
.col-sm-6 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
.Data{
background-color: darkturquoise;
    width: 100%;
    height:inherit;
}
.col-sm-6 .col-sm-12 {
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.col-sm-6 .col-sm-12:last-child{
margin: 0;
}

.col-sm-6 .col-sm-12 .Data {
height:100%;
    background-color: aqua;

}


.NoPadding {
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `calc` to calculate the appropriate `height`

Update your css to this:

```
.col-sm-6 .col-sm-12 {
  height: calc(50% - 5px); /* calculate height with the margin */
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1za2mdtc/1/)

Comment: Carlo , thanks for the answer,  i have  a problem when i add a padding or margin in the div.container , the child become out of the parent  , how i recalculate them ?

Comment: @MohamedSamy Seems no problem to me when adding padding and margin to `div.container`. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1za2mdtc/4/). If you want, you can create a fiddle and I would be happy to check.

Comment: Thanks , i will try  with myself , but thanks for ur answer